# How do I create a while loop that will continue to run as long as the user inputs the proper tag/code at the end of each loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm decently new to programming, and I'm taking an introductory course at my high school right now. One of the assignments we're working on right now is a program that asks the user what formula they would like to calculate (various area/volume/etc types of formulas), asks them for the data needed to make the calculation, and then gives them the answer. I've gotten really interested in programming mostly due to this assignment, because I've realized just how much of a brain teaser this work can be.

With that, I decided to go a little bit above and beyond. I cleaned up my messy code, and I'm now trying to make a while loop that will allow the user to continue calculating formulas without running the program again, as well as give them an error message when they input improper data. I've figured out the latter part, but I want to implement the former before putting the solution to the second issue into the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FormulaRemake {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n","What formula would you like to calculate?","Area of a Circle (AOC)","Circumference of a Circle (COC)","Area of a Trapezoid (AOT)","Volume of a Cylinder (VOC)","Volume of a Sphere (VOS)","Volume of a Cone (VON)");
    String formula = input.nextLine();

    while((formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOC"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("COC"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOT"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOC"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOS"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VON")))
            {
        if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOC"))
        {
            System.out.println("What is the circle's radius?");
            double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("%.2f",Math.PI*(Math.pow(inputRadius,2)));

        }

        if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("COC"))
        {
            System.out.print("What is the circle's radius?");
        double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.2f",2*Math.PI*inputRadius);
        }

        if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOT"))
        {
            System.out.println("What is the height of the trapezoid?");
            double inputHeight = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the first length of the trapezoid?");
            double inputLengthFirst = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the second length of the trapezoid?");
            double inputLengthSecond = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("%.2f",(1/2)*inputHeight*(inputLengthFirst+inputLengthSecond));
        }

        if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOC"))
        {
            System.out.println("What is the cylinder's radius?");
            double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the cylinder's height?");
            double inputHeight = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("%.2f",(Math.PI*(Math.pow(inputRadius,2)*inputHeight)));
        }

        if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOS"))
        {
            System.out.println("What is the sphere's radius?");
            double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( inputRadius, 3 ));
            System.out.printf("%.2f",(4.0/3.0)*Math.PI*Math.pow(inputRadius, 3));
        }

        if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VON"))
        {
            System.out.println("What is the cone's radius?");
            double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the cone's height?");
            double inputHeight = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("%.2f",(1.0/3.0)*Math.PI*(Math.pow(inputRadius,2)*inputHeight));  
            }

}


}
}
```

I have a while line, but I'm not really sure what to do with it. I don't know how to make my code loop while (hehe, while) the active line is within the while block. Should I be saving this class, creating a new class, then referencing it in another class, like

string mathDone = true (at the end of every equation)

```
while(mathDone.equalsIgnoreCase(true))
{
String continueCalculation = input.nextLine;
System.out.println("Would you like to continue calculation?");
if(continueCalculation.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))||(continueCalulation.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

{
    (whatever the run command is goes here) formulaRemake
}
}

asides from that, I'm kind of clueless. I know there are posts on stackoverflow on a similar topic, but I can't figure out how to apply them to my situation. I'm too new (and clearly, too stupid) to figure out how to use those posts to help me.

Comment: Picking a language and adding it as a tag to your question would be a good start. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You know, I thought I did. I had two separate tabs open, one with poor grammar and another with proper grammar.

It appears to be that I copy and pasted the wrong topic into the wrong tab post-editing. Major apologies ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is kind of a menu, even though it would be with only two options:

1. Choose and calculate a formula
2. Quit

The code for the first option is already available. I assume that it works properly. The fastest way (but not recommended) would be to put your entire code in a while loop. I would recommend you to let the main function only have this while loop, which calls another function, where you put in your current code. If you do not know what functions are yet: they are helpful in many ways and one of them is to make code more readable, since you keep the essential part of your code at one place. For example if you have a very long math task, which is needed to be calculated in many places in your code, it would be better to not copy this calculation into every single part, where it is needed and you could call many code lines with only one line.

EDIT for clarification:

The way your program is now, with everything being in one function (the main function), will just get longer if you keep programing this way. The occurring problems here are, that the longer your code gets, the less readable and maintainable it becomes. While this may not be a problem for a little testing program, you will encounter the mentioned problems in a group project or in a company etc.

To deal with these problems you can change your code by adding functions, which is probably the next chapter you should check out. Functions/Methods are parts of the code, which can be called from every place, where you allow it. This is what a function basically looks like:

```
visibility static/nonStatic type functionName (parameterType parameterName) {
//codebody
}
```

visibility: either public, private, package (if omitted) or protected
We will use only public right now, which means, that the function is available everywhere.
static or nonStatic (if omitted): static means "once per class", which makes the function available either by an instance (nonStatic) or the class (static). But this is not that important for you now.
Type: The return type of the function. You can choose one datatype and return an instance of the chosen class/datatype to the point where the function was called. If nothing shall/must be returned, you can chose the type void.
functionName: can be chosen freely. Note: Use camelCase
Parameter list: (parameterType1 param1, parameterType2 param2, ... ), e.g. (int a, String b). In the function you have an int a now and a String b.

Your program would then look like this:

```
//Now your calculations etc are put into this function.
//Now you can write simply myFunction() somewhere else (outside of this function) 
//and the execution of the code where the function is called will be
//stopped and wait until the function is finished (until the code of
//the function is executed)
public static void myFunction() { 

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n","What formula would you like to calculate?","Area of a Circle (AOC)","Circumference of a Circle (COC)","Area of a Trapezoid (AOT)","Volume of a Cylinder (VOC)","Volume of a Sphere (VOS)","Volume of a Cone (VON)");
String formula = input.nextLine();

while((formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOC"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("COC"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOT"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOC"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOS"))||(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VON")))
        {
    if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOC"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is the circle's radius?");
        double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.2f",Math.PI*(Math.pow(inputRadius,2)));

    }

    if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("COC"))
    {
        System.out.print("What is the circle's radius?");
    double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("%.2f",2*Math.PI*inputRadius);
    }

    if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("AOT"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is the height of the trapezoid?");
        double inputHeight = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the first length of the trapezoid?");
        double inputLengthFirst = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the second length of the trapezoid?");
        double inputLengthSecond = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.2f",(1/2)*inputHeight*(inputLengthFirst+inputLengthSecond));
    }

    if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOC"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is the cylinder's radius?");
        double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the cylinder's height?");
        double inputHeight = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.2f",(Math.PI*(Math.pow(inputRadius,2)*inputHeight)));
    }

    if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VOS"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is the sphere's radius?");
        double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( inputRadius, 3 ));
        System.out.printf("%.2f",(4.0/3.0)*Math.PI*Math.pow(inputRadius, 3));
    }
    if(formula.equalsIgnoreCase("VON"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is the cone's radius?");
        double inputRadius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the cone's height?");
        double inputHeight = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.2f",(1.0/3.0)*Math.PI*(Math.pow(inputRadius,2)*inputHeight));
    }
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) { //the main function, containing only the menu loop
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean stop = false;
  while(!stop) { //menu loop
    myFunction(); //Your formulas will be calculated in this function
    System.out.println("Do you want to calculate another formula? 0: no, 1: yes")//ask the user if another calculation shall be done
    int userInput = input.nextInt();
    if (userInput == 0) {//set stop accordingly, stop = true will exit the loop
      stop = true;
    } else if (userInput == 1) { //
      stop = false;
    }

  }
}
```

One last thing I have to note: The function is still very long this way and very unreadable. Your next step could be to make the code more readable by further splitting the function into smaller functions (you can call a function inside of another function)

Comment: I kind of understand what you're saying, but.. not quite. :P

When you say "enter the code, preparations etc" are you referring to stuff like declaring variables and whatnot, then implementing the boolean/while and the function, and then having the actual code body with the mathematical functions at the bottom?

Comment: Sorry I confused you^^ In this part I recommend you to declare variables and do everything that should be executed before you enter your loop. I know that in the code you showed this would probably only be the case with scanner, which has to be initialized for asking the user if the program should continue or stop, but I thought to confuse you less in case that there is more code, that you probably did not include in your question, so that you do not assume that you may not put anything in the main function except the while loop.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you to split your code into functions. Of course your program will work as well if you put a loop around it, but this is bad practice if you think long term. While it will be ok now and you will know how your program works and where what gets executed, you will not know it in lets say a month, when you come back to revisit how you have done it. And whats worse when you work with someone on the same code, they will have to/ want to be able to read your code easily.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't grasp exactly what I'm trying to do here. It might be because I have an unobtainable goal in mind (because Java doesn't support what I want), but I think my OP might have been worded poorly.

I want to run the code normally when it is first ran, then after the first formula is solved, I want the user to either input another formula code, or "done" to say that the program to terminate, but I'm not sure how to go about that. 

I don't know how to utilize functions to do what you're recommending (put the main function in a while loop that is called upon).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to define my formula block as a function, nor am I sure how to call upon it somewhere else. If you could create a pseudocode block that exemplifies what you're talking about, I would greatly appreciate it and forever be in your debt :)

Comment: I just wanted to say that you are my savior! I didn't expect nearly as much explanation or assistance as you provided. I'm going through all of the rest of the work I've done so far and I'm going to clean all of them up with functions - my only question left, I suppose, is how can I make this cleaner? Could I make a package with one class that asks the user which program they want to run, then call upon functions from different classes that are packaged together? Something like a first console where the user says "I want to use a math formula", then it runs this code here.

Comment: After the code runs, and they no longer want to compute more functions, they are kicked back to the first menu, where they can access other stuff (the other user input assignments I've done so far). Then when they're done with that, the whole thing terminates. 

@Ivo Vidovic

Comment: To the first comment: You're welcome! How to make code "cleaner" is actually a very big question, where a real answer will probably never be found. Basically what people do is learning from mistakes and analyzing bad practices and trying to make concepts to avoid getting in trouble later on. For beginners it is good to take it step by step. First you should learn how to use functions (how to use return, a recursion, parameters, etc). By using functions your code will automatically get cleaner. Even if you need a very long function (still try avoiding that), your code will get cleaner

Comment: To the first comment:
If you want to learn about classes next, you will have to deal with the term object orientation. This is quite a big step for many people, but sooner or later you will have to deal with it anyway. There are a lot of questions on SO on this topic and there is a lot of documentation and literature about how to use classes etc. To the second comment: If this behavior is undesired you can change the while inside myFunction to an if, making it a check if the user put in a supported formula, or omit this while, then the function will always return the user to the menu

Answer (score 1):

Use continue and break statement, for example:

```
i=input;

while(true)
{
  if(i==1){break;}
  else
  {
    i=input;
    continue;
  }
}
```